# How to hide items on navbar from user?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jsp-tags

```
    This is my items on navbar

               <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="navbar-brand1" href="#">User Accounts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="navbar-brand1" href="#">Lecture</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="navbar-brand1" href="#">Quiz</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="navbar-brand1" href="#">Record</a>
                </div>
```

I want to hide "User Account" item if students logged in, on the other hand hides "Lecture and Quiz" item if admin logged in. I already have login function with user_type "student" and "admin" already. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. We are **happy to help** provided **you tried something by yourself** and that did not work out.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: This would require just some simple JavaScript. Just use document.getElementById('elemId').style.display = 'none'; based on the conditions in your question. You will need to find out if they are logged in which of course means a server-side language like PHP.

Comment: What does this have to do with `java`?

Comment: Simply use standard JSTL <c:if/> tag to determine of the links should be rendered http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm

Comment: @AlanHay - Hi, thanks a lot, it's very useful Im just new in JSTL and has 0 knowledge about the tags. thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this java script function :

```
 function usersetting(usertype)
    {
        if(usertype== "student") {
                 $(".form-group a").each(function() {
                     if($(this).text()=="User Account"){
                         $(this).parent().hide();
                         }
                     else {  
                         $(this).parent().show();
                     }
                 });
        }
        else if(usertype== "admin") {
      $(".form-group a").each(function() {
                     if($(this).text()=="Lecture and Quiz") {
                         $(this).parent().hide();
                     }
                     else {  
                         $(this).parent().show();
                     }
                 });
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this may be possible in JS, it would seem to be (a) unsecure and (b) overkill - simpler solutions exist.

Comment: then call remove() insted of hide() @AlanHay

Comment: If the elements should not be output then this should be dealt with server side and not client side. Perfectly simple server side solutions exist using standard JSTL tags so JS is not required.

Comment: @AlanHay His question is only to hide the navbar  from user.

Comment: --closed--
thanks a lot guys..
@Rakin - thanks for your js people might search about js on doing things like this so i'll accept your answer. but i go for alanhay suggestion since Im working on jstl tags. thanks anyway .. :)